# Can you draw a sphere using TeX?

Tags: draw

I'm pretty new to TeX apart from MathJax, and I don't know exactly how am I going to draw a sphere using some variation of TeX apart from MathJax.

So if I use `\sphere` on MathJax, it won't pop up and just give out an error. I tried it on Mathematics SE.

So how can I draw a sphere using TeX? I don't know what to use since I'm new.

Comment: How are you intending to distinguish your sphere from a circle?  By shading?

Comment: Shading, but you can also do the broken lines at the back of it.